# Putting a GFCI on another GFCIs LOAD

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have two GFCIs, can I connect the second GFCI on the first GFCIs LOAD? I know I can connect them in parallel, but  I'm curious what this would do.

Comment: It's a pain in the a$$.  If the second trips, so will the first.  And they must be reset in order 1 then 2. Don't do it.

Comment: Also there is no point in doing this. The first one will protect all receptacles downstream on the load.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### There's no point

First, a GFCI receptacle can protect regular receptacles downstream (that's why there are LOAD terminals on them downstream).  Second, connecting two GFCIs in series creates a race condition if a ground fault is placed downstream of the 2nd GFCI -- it's indeterminate which one trips (it's even possible for both to trip on the same fault, as Tyson points out in his comment).  Third, modern GFCIs require power to reset, so you'd have to reset them in order when they do both trip.  All in all, it's a needless pain in the arse that's best avoided.

Comment: Thanks, both of you gave me what I wanted to know and it makes sense. I chose your answer, but can't upvote it due to lack of points.

Comment: Speaking of "no point" you no longer have that problem OP.